# Can't Delete ARP Cache on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, arp

When I enter the command line `arp -d *` at an instance of cmd.exe, I get

`The ARP entry deletion failed: The parameter is incorrect`

I can delete individual entries fine, e.g. `arp -d 192.168.1.1`

I also have Cygwin and Git Bash installed, so I thought maybe the `*` was getting expanded like in a Unix shell, but it doesn't appear so, as `echo *` from cmd.exe results in a simple `*` output.  I have also tried escaping the asterisk and enclosing it in quotes with `arp -d "*"` and `arp -d ^*`.  Both result in the same error.

I do have two NICs on this machine, an internal and a USB, but I get the same error when I unplug the USB NIC.

The account I am running from is an administrator, and I have also tried right-clicking cmd.exe and selecting "Run as Administrator."

Comment: Same result confirmed on Win10 Pro.

Comment: Hm, is this something I just haven't noticed yet on Win7?  The '*' wildcard is supposed to be supported according to the `arp -help` documentation, and it used to work in XP...

Comment: This happened to me on two HP machines that I recently restored to the original factory settings. All of the other machines of the same model had no issues with this command. This was using Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the command `netsh interface ip delete arpcache`

You can then run `arp -a` to confirm that the entries have gone.

[Clear, Delete and Refresh ARP Cache Entry](https://techjourney.net/clear-delete-and-refresh-arp-cache-entry/)

Comment: Yes, that works thanks!  I'm going to leave the question open for now though, since the arp command line utility is supposed to work as well, and there's not good reason for them to break something that used to work...

Answer (score 1):

I tried delete the ARP Cache with the arp -d command and showed me "The ARP entry deletion failed: The parameter is incorrect" then I tried with netsh interface ip delete arpcache command and it worked and then I tried with the arp -d command again and it worked.